# many to many condition in eager loading with sequelize

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

I want to load a `User` with all its `Organisation` and all the `Team` of the user via `RelUserTeam` for the organisation of the user:

```js
const user = await User.findOne({
    where: { _id: "x-y-z-a-b" },
    include: [
      Organisation, 
      { model: Team, where: { organisation: Sequelize.col("Organisation._id") } }
    ],
  });
```

Relations:

```js
const teamForeignKey = generateForeignKey("team");
const userForeignKey = generateForeignKey("user");

User.belongsTo(Organisation, organisationForeignKey);
Organisation.hasMany(User, organisationForeignKey);
User.belongsToMany(Team, { ...userForeignKey, through: RelUserTeam });
Team.belongsToMany(User, { ...teamForeignKey, through: RelUserTeam });

Team.belongsTo(Organisation, organisationForeignKey);
Organisation.hasMany(Team, organisationForeignKey);
```

This generate a queries that crash:

```
SELECT ...
FROM "User" AS "User" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Organisation" AS "Organisation" 
ON "User"."organisation" = "Organisation"."_id" 
INNER JOIN ( 
  "RelUserTeam" AS "Teams->RelUserTeam" 
  INNER JOIN "Team" AS "Teams" ON "Teams"."_id" = "Teams->RelUserTeam"."team"
  ) 
ON "User"."_id" = "Teams->RelUserTeam"."user" AND "Organisation"."_id" 
WHERE "User"."_id" = 'x-y-z-a-b';
```

Error is:

```
argument of AND must be type boolean, not type uuid
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `AND "Organisation"."_id"` ? There should be an equal sign or other comparator after that.

Comment: Yes that's the problem, but I don't know how to fix it in my sequelize code

Comment: I guess this part `where: { organisation: Sequelize.col("Organisation._id") }` is creating the wrong query.  How `Team` and `Organisation` is associated?

Comment: @Emma I updated the "relations" part of my question to include the team-organisation relation

Comment: You should use the nested association for that. Instead of `where: { organisation: ...}`, try `include: Organisation`